# Как оптимизировать код вычисления дат?

Tags: инспекция-кода, pascalabc.net

Задали задачу:

> Дата некоторого дня характеризуется тремя натуральными числами: g(год), m(порядковый номер месяца) и n(число). По заданным g, n и m определить:
>
> а) Дату предыдущего дня;
> б) Дату следующего дня.
>
> В обеих задачах рассмотреть два случая:
>
> 1. Заданный год не является високосным;
> 2. Заданный год может быть високосным.

Можно ли код сделать более рациональным? Можно ли case использовать один раз вместо двух?

```
program n_4_114;
var g, m, n, gp, mp, np, last, z, f: integer;
 begin
   f := 28; //данная содержит в себе последний день февраля
   Writeln('Учитывать високосные года?', #10, '1) Да', #10, '2) Нет', #10, 'В ответ укажите только число - 1, или 2.'); 
   Readln(z);
   Writeln('Введите год.');
   Readln(g);
   while g < 1 do //Проверка корректности года
  begin
    Writeln('Вы ввели некорректный год! Пожалуйста, введите другой!');
    Readln(g);
  end;
  if z=1 then // z=1, если пользователь решил учитывать високосные года. Тело условия проверяет год, и если он високосный - меняет переменную f (последний день февраля на 29)
  begin
    if g mod 100 = 0 then
    begin
    z:= g mod 400;
    end
    else z := g mod 4;
    if z=0 then f:=29
  end;
   Writeln('Введите месяц.');
   Readln(m);
  while (m < 1)or(m > 12) do //Проверка корректности месяца
  begin
    Writeln('Вы ввели некорректный месяц! Пожалуйста, введите другой!');
    Readln(m);
  end;
  case m of  //Используем "case" для определения последнего дня месяца (last), ради правильной проверки корректности введенного пользователем дня
    1,3,5,7,8,10,12: last:=31; //Для месяцев в которых 31-день
    4,6,9,11: last:=30; //Для месяцев в которых 30-день
    2: last:=f;
  end;
   Writeln('Введите день.');
   Readln(n);
  while (n < 1) or (n > last) do //Проверка корректности дня
  begin
    Writeln('Вы ввели некоректный день! Пожалуйста, введите другой!');
    Readln(n);
  end;
  np := n + 1; //определяем следующий день 
  n := n - 1; // определяем предыдущий день. чтобы не создавать лишних переменных, используем переменную n для хранении данных о предыдущем дне. Аналогично мы поступим и с переменными m и g
  mp := m; //дублируем переменную месяца в mp для дальнейших операций с ней (это необходимо, т.к. в итоге месяц предыдущего и следующего дней могут отличаться) Аналогично мы поступим и с переменной g.
  gp := g;
  if np > last then //проверяем, принадлежит ли следующий день следующему месяцу
  begin
    np := 1;
    mp := mp + 1;
  end;
  if mp > 12 then //проверяем, не принадлежит ли следующий месяц следующему году
  begin
    gp := g + 1;
    mp := 1;
  end;
  if n < 1 then //проверяем, принадлежит ли предыдущий день предыдущему месяцу
  begin
    m := m - 1;
    case m of  //определяем последний день предыдущего месяца
    1,3,5,7,8,10,12: n:=31; 
    4,6,9,11: n:=30; 
    2: n:=f;
    0: //если мы получили m=0, то по факту это значит что предыдущий день - 31/12 предыдущего года
     begin
      g := g - 1;
      n := 31;
      m := 12;
     end;
    end;
   end;
   if g = 0 then Writeln('Дата следующего дня: ',np,'/',mp,'/',gp,'. Дата предыдущего дня: 31/12/1 год до нашей эры.')//если g=0, мы не можем записать "нулевой год", ведь его не было. Вместе него запишем последний день до нашей эры
   else Writeln('Дата следующего дня: ',np,'/',mp,'/',gp,'. Дата предыдущего дня: ',n,'/',m,'/',g,'.');
 end.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
uses System.Globalization;

begin
  CultureInfo.CurrentCulture := new CultureInfo('ru-RU');
  loop 6 do
  begin
    var (День, Месяц, Год) := ReadInteger3('Введите день, месяц и год:');
    var Сегодня := new DateTime(Год, Месяц, День);
    var Вчера := Сегодня.AddDays(-1);
    var Завтра := Сегодня.AddDays(1);
    $'Вчерашний день: {Вчера.Day}.{Вчера.Month}.{Вчера.Year}'.Println;
    $'Завтрашний день: {Завтра.Day}.{Завтра.Month}.{Завтра.Year}'.Println
  end;
end.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]